# What is the site that lets you create an install package of your commonly used Windows applications?

Tags: windows, installation, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One-stop-shop installer for free Windows software?](https://superuser.com/questions/69751/one-stop-shop-installer-for-free-windows-software)

What is the site that lets you create an install package of your commonly used Windows applications?

This is probably a dupe but I can't find it here or using the Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) is what you're looking for.